# Per pixel scrolling in QPlainTextEdit

Tags: python, c++, qt, qt6

When scrolling any widget, we can notice that it moves by pixels. But in the case of QPlainTextEdit, things are a little different. It scrolls not by pixels, but by lines. That is, we will never see any line being only half visible.
A similar problem occurs in QTableWidget, but there it is solved by setting the scrolling mode.

```cpp
this->setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel)
```

I did not find such functionality in QPlainTextEdit. Is it possible to somehow get around this and implement pixel-by-pixel scrolling?

The `setSingleStep` method doesn't help either. Even with its use, the widget scrolls line by line.

Comment: It's extremely difficult with QPlainTextEdit: its implementation requires to have the vertical scroll bar strictly linked to the line numbers, due to the way the underlying QTextDocument layout works (in fact, the returned height of the document size is not in pixels, but in line count). It's not completely impossible, but it would require to override a lot of aspects, and it may become unreliable if not done with extreme care and awareness of all objects in play (QTextDocument, QPlainTextDocumentLayout, QAbstractScrollArea, etc.). Use QTextEdit.

Comment: QPlainTextEdit is optimized for speed even woth large texts, at least compared to QTextEdit. If you don't meed this extra performance, just use QTextEdit.

Comment: @hyde, the problem is that I need more performance

Comment: @musicamante It turns out that without overriding methods there is no way to set the pixel position for the scrollbar?

Comment: @OKwy Without overriding, no. The default behavior uses a vertical offset based on lines, and set through private functions that are internally called and cannot be overridden. And even if you try to override available methods (like `scrollContentsBy`) and use some workaround (setting a custom QScrollBar, or using a dummy one while hiding the real one), it's still possible that it won't work properly anyway due to the very specific way the QPlainTextDocumentLayout works and how the widget paints its contents.